# I need Oauth2 token for Google Data API with client ID and client secret for React app

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, google-analytics-api, google-api-js-client

I want to fetch data from google analytics via google data api. The request is given below.

```
export async function fetchAnalyticsData() {
  //   getAccessToken();

  const GA4_PROPERTY_ID = "";
  const url = `https://analyticsdata.googleapis.com/v1beta/properties/${GA4_PROPERTY_ID}:runReport`;

  const requestOptions = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      // Add your authorization token here if required
      Authorization: "Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      dateRanges: [{ startDate: "2023-09-01", endDate: "2023-09-15" }],
      dimensions: [{ name: "country" }],
      metrics: [{ name: "activeUsers" }],
    }),
  };

  try {
    const response = await fetch(url, requestOptions);
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data); // Do whatever you need with the data
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
  }
}
```

This request gives 401. "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential".

So, I created Oauth2 client id and client secret:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDSSU.png)

How can i take a token for the request by using client id and secret if possible. I do not want users to login.
-

Comment: Do you want to use JavaScript or nodejs

Comment: You need an oauth2 client. https://oauth.net/code

Comment: Does the app have the necessary scopes for accessing analytics APIs?

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo I want to use JS

Comment: @vicki My app is connected to Google Analytics. I can see the analytics data in "analytics.google.com". I want to show the analytics data on my website

Comment: I have a sample that works with client-side JavaScript but currently it's only loading from the real-time report it's not loading from the standard report. Would this be something you're interested in it's kind of big

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo I would like to see what you have done if it does not take your time too much

Comment: There you go give that a try let me know if you have any issues

Answer (score 0):

This is my sample for accessing the real-time API you're going to have to change it to work with the standard reports

## config.js

```
const appConfig = {
  'CLIENT_ID' :  'READACTEd',
  'API_KEY' : 'REDACTED',
  'PROPERTY_ID':'250796939'
}
```

## realtime.js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Gmail API Quickstart</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.charts.load('current', {
            'packages':['geochart'],
        });
        function drawRegionsMap(mapData) {
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(mapData);

            var options = {};

            var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('regions_div'));

            chart.draw(data, options);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<p>google analytics data API realtime Quickstart</p>

<!--Add buttons to initiate auth sequence and sign out-->
<button id="authorize_button" onclick="handleAuthClick()">Authorize</button>
<button id="signout_button" onclick="handleSignoutClick()">Sign Out</button>

<pre id="content" style="white-space: pre-wrap;"></pre>
<script src="config.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    /* exported gapiLoaded */
    /* exported gisLoaded */
    /* exported handleAuthClick */
    /* exported handleSignoutClick */

    // TODO(developer): Set to client ID and API key from the Developer Console
    const CLIENT_ID = appConfig.CLIENT_ID
    const API_KEY = appConfig.API_KEY

    // Discovery doc URL for APIs used by the quickstart
    const DISCOVERY_DOC = 'https://analyticsdata.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1beta';

    // Authorization scopes required by the API; multiple scopes can be
    // included, separated by spaces.
    const SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly';

    const PROPERTY_ID = appConfig.PROPERTY_ID

    let tokenClient;
    let gapiInited = false;
    let gisInited = false;

    document.getElementById('authorize_button').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById('signout_button').style.visibility = 'hidden';

    /**
     * Callback after api.js is loaded.
     */
    function gapiLoaded() {
        gapi.load('client', initializeGapiClient);
    }

    /**
     * Callback after the API client is loaded. Loads the
     * discovery doc to initialize the API.
     */
    async function initializeGapiClient() {
        await gapi.client.init({
            apiKey: API_KEY,
            discoveryDocs: [DISCOVERY_DOC],
        });
        gapiInited = true;
        maybeEnableButtons();
    }

    /**
     * Callback after Google Identity Services are loaded.
     */
    function gisLoaded() {
        tokenClient = google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
            client_id: CLIENT_ID,
            scope: SCOPES,
            callback: '', // defined later
        });
        gisInited = true;
        maybeEnableButtons();
    }

    /**
     * Enables user interaction after all libraries are loaded.
     */
    function maybeEnableButtons() {
        if (gapiInited && gisInited) {
            document.getElementById('authorize_button').style.visibility = 'visible';
            if (localStorage.getItem('accessToken')) {
                handleAuthClick()
            }
        }

    }

    /**
     *  Sign in the user upon button click.
     */
    function handleAuthClick() {
        tokenClient.callback = async (resp) => {
            if (resp.error !== undefined) {
                throw (resp);
            }
            document.getElementById('signout_button').style.visibility = 'visible';
            document.getElementById('authorize_button').innerText = 'Refresh';
            const token = gapi.client.getToken();
            localStorage.setItem('accessToken', token.access_token);
            await getRealTime();
        };

        if (localStorage.getItem('accessToken')) {
            // get saved access token.
            access_token = localStorage.getItem('accessToken')
            // set it in the client
            gapi.client.setToken({ access_token: access_token });
            const token = gapi.client.getToken();
            //document.getElementById('content').innerText = "Reading from local storage: " + token.access_token
            getRealTime();
            document.getElementById('signout_button').style.visibility = 'visible';
            document.getElementById('authorize_button').innerText = 'Refresh';

        } else if (gapi.client.getToken() === null) {
            // Prompt the user to select a Google Account and ask for consent to share their data
            // when establishing a new session.
            tokenClient.requestAccessToken({prompt: 'consent'});
        } else {
            // Skip display of account chooser and consent dialog for an existing session.
            tokenClient.requestAccessToken({prompt: ''});
            const token = gapi.client.getToken();
            // save the access token to localstorage to prevent loss during a refresh
            localStorage.setItem('accessToken', token.access_token);
        }
    }

    /**
     *  Sign out the user upon button click.
     */
    function handleSignoutClick() {
        const token = gapi.client.getToken();
        if (token !== null) {
            // Clear the access token from the client and the local storage.
            gapi.client.setToken('');
            localStorage.removeItem('accessToken');
            document.getElementById('content').innerText = '';
            document.getElementById('authorize_button').innerText = 'Authorize';
            document.getElementById('signout_button').style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
    }

    /**
     * Realtime reports show events and usage data for the periods of time ranging
     * from the present moment to 30 minutes ago (up to 60 minutes for Google Analytics
     * 360 properties) and can be used for applications such as live counters of visitors
     * on your website.
     */
    async function getRealTime() {
        let response;
        try {
            response = await gapi.client.analyticsdata.properties.runRealtimeReport({
                'property': 'properties/' + PROPERTY_ID,
                dimensions: [{ name: 'country', },],
                metrics: [{ name: 'activeUsers', },],
            });
        } catch (err) {
            document.getElementById('content').innerText = err.message;
            return;
        }
        const data = response.result;

        if (!data) {
            document.getElementById('content').innerText = 'Error requesting profile.';
            return;
        }

        const jsonString = JSON.stringify(data);

        const rows = data.rows
        if (!rows) {
            document.getElementById('content').innerText = 'No data ' + jsonString;
            return;
        }

        const formattedData = [];

        // Add the header row
        formattedData.push(['city', 'activeUsers']);

        // Process each data item
        for (const row of rows) {
            const city = row.dimensionValues[0].value;
            const activeUsers = parseInt(row.metricValues[0].value);

            // Add the formatted data row
            formattedData.push([city, activeUsers]);
        }


        drawRegionsMap(formattedData)
        //document.getElementById('content').innerText = jsonString
    }
</script>
<script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js" onload="gapiLoaded()"></script>
<script async defer src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" onload="gisLoaded()"></script>
<div id="regions_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This should be enough to get you started until I have time to create another sample for the standard reports

Comment: I simply want to show "page visit counter" on my website. It shouldn't need any kind of login. I just want to use runReport request but it needs oauth2 token. And I want to get the token in code without login

Comment: That's not how access works Google Analytics private user data you're going to have to be logged in if you want to see the data.  the fact of the matter is is if you're using JavaScript then it's going to be the data of the user who is signing in so it's not going to be **your** Google Analytics data